# Get last element of an array

Tags: java, database, postman

through an API I get an array with a lot of different data. But I only need the last element.

The variable sb has the array in it. But i cannot access elements like that: sb[0] (for example)

If I print the variable sb it looks like that:

```
{"data":[[[1583596801195,279.52],[1583596814340,279.52],[1583596815535,279.44563849372383],[1583596816730,279.2060000000001],[1583596913525,279.2060000000001],[1583596914720,279.28824435146447],[1583596915915,279.52],[1583597211080,279.52],[1583597212275,279.52000000000004],[1583597213470,279.52],[1583597609015,279.52],[1583597610210,279.5199999999999],[1583597707005,279.5199999999999],[1583597708200,279.52000000000004],[1583597709395,279.52],[1583597806190,279.52],[1583597807385,279.52000000000004],[1583597993805,279.52000000000004]]]}
```

In this case, I only need the last element (279.52000000000004).

My code look like that:

```
    URL url = new URL("the URL i get the data from");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    InputStream instream = con.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            instream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
```

Sorry I am not experienced that experienced with programming. But I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That looks like json data, did you try to parse it as json?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the last element only, you should not be appending the results.

Instead, replace the previous value stored.

```
String result = null;
String line = null;
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        //sb.append(line + "\n");
        result = line; // not appending, but replacing
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        instream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Yes that would make sense. But the problem is that I don't have access to the database where these elements are stored.

Comment: @virw Would that matter, as you need the last result, and you will be storing that only at last iteration

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I understand it correctly.
If I do it this way I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, replace this line "`System.out.println(sb)` with below code :

```
String s = new String(sb);
String d[] = s.split(",");  
System.out.println(d[d.length -1].replaceAll("]", ""));
```

This would print the exact data you want i.e `279.52000000000004`